# unable to scrape all the elements of a webpage while javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrape a non-English website, but there is a problem. When I disable javascript in the given URL, only 10 containers are shown although there are a lot more containers, and thus, my spider can only scrape 10 of them.
By the way, there is no "more" button on the page, the only way is to scroll down and wait till the next 10 containers get loaded and this won't happen while javascript is disabled.

What can I do to be able to scrape all the containers while javascript is disabled?

Thank you,

Here is my code:

```
    def parse(self, response):
        containers = response.xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12']")
        for container in containers:
            doctor_name = container.xpath(".//div[@class='dr_name']/text()").get()
            doctor_specialty = container.xpath(".//h3[@class='row dr_proficiency']/text()").get()
            visited_count = container.xpath(".//div[@class='visited_count']/text()").get()
            viewpoint_number = container.xpath(".//span[@class='count']/text()").get()
            address = container.xpath(".//div[@class='row dr_address']/text()").get()
            yield{
                'doctor_name':doctor_name,
                'doctor_specialty':doctor_specialty,
                'visited_count':visited_count,
                'viewpoint_number':viewpoint_number,
                'address':address
            }
```

Comment: Chances are the javascript you aren’t running is what normally runs to retrieves all those other containers after the page loads in a browser. Guess you’ll have to look at .g. Selenium to run a headless browser which does execute the JS.

Comment: The other route is to reverse engineer or trace execution n a browser to find the URLs the JS retrieves to populate the other containers, and program those requests into your code - not this is fragile because if the page changes it may start using different urls.